# How to resolve error: cannot allocate vector of size 70.7 Gb in RStudio?

Tags: r, netcdf, netcdf4

I need to convert .nc file (size 35 GB) to .csv. It is showing an error saying : cannot allocate vector of size 70.7 Gb

How to resolve this error?

I have successfully converted .nc files (size 4 kb) to .csv files using the same code that I am using to convert larger files.

I tried to clear the memory using gc() command before nc.df... command. Also, I tried to increase memory limit as below.

```
              > memory.limit()
              [1] 16306

              > memory.limit(size = 120000)
              [1] 120000
```

The code is as follows:

```
   > rm(list = ls())
   > library(raster)
   > nc.brick <- brick(file.choose())
   > nc.df <- as.data.frame(nc.brick, xy=T)
   > write.csv(nc.df, file.choose())
```

The expected result is to get a .csv file using the above code. However, presently, after second last command (i.e.,  nc.df <- as.data.frame(nc.brick, xy=T), it gives the said error i.e., Error: cannot allocate vector of size 70.7 Gb.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200) 

Matrix products: default 

locale: 
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252 
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C 
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.

1252 attached base packages: 
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base 

other attached packages: 
[1] raster_2.5-8 sp_1.2-4 RevoUtilsMath_10.0.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached): 
[1] compiler_3.4.0 RevoUtils_10.0.4 rgdal_1.2-7 tools_3.4.0 Rcpp_0.12.10 ncdf4_1.16
[7] grid_3.4.0 lattice_0.20-35
```

I tried library ff but it is again giving the same error.

```
            > rm(list = ls())
            > library(ff)
            > nc.brick <- brick(file.choose())
            > nc.df <- as.data.frame(nc.brick, xy=T)
```

Comment: Hi, can you post the result of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: @SamuelDiebolt  sessionInfo() result is as follows:                                               
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

continued....

Comment: locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] raster_2.5-8         sp_1.2-4             RevoUtilsMath_10.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0   RevoUtils_10.0.4 rgdal_1.2-7      tools_3.4.0      Rcpp_0.12.10     ncdf4_1.16                     continued...

Comment: [7] grid_3.4.0       lattice_0.20-35

Comment: Since R runs in-memory, do you have over enough available RAM to handle a 70GB+ data frame? You could also try to use libraries to handle big data frames, like `ff`.

Comment: I dont have available RAM to handle 70GB+ data frame. I tried library(ff) as shown in the post but got the same error. Pls check the post and let me know if I did it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `?raster::as.data.frame` :

> If there is insufficient memory to load all values, you can use getValues or getValuesBlock to read chunks of the file. You could also first use sampleRegular

You can use `getValues` or `getValuesBlock` in a loop to process your file by chunks (using `append = TRUE` in `write.csv`).

You could also downsample your raster with `sampleRegular` to make your raster smaller. Only you can decide whether downsampling is appropriate in your case.

Comment: After defining the nc.brick as above,  I have used following code to prepare nc.df file:  nc.df <- as.data.frame(getValues(nc.brick, 5)[4]). In this, I have chosen 5th row and 4th column. It has given me the value corresponding to the respective row and column. But, in my output I would like to have all the four columns from row 2 to 5 (i.e., row 2 to 5 and column 1 to 4). In that case, how should we define the row and colum in getvalues?

Comment: @Olive This is what getValuesBlock does: `getValuesBlock(nc.brick, row = 2, nrows = 3, col = 1, ncols = 3)`. Not 100% sure of the argument names but you get the idea.